# Get channel ID of newly created channel - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to get the channel ID of a channel that gets created when a user reacts to a message with a specific emoji. The creation of the channel works perfectly, the only problem is that I have trouble getting the ID of that created channel.

I use the following code for creating the channel:

```js
await message.guild.channels.create(`│${name}`, {
    type: 'text',
    parent: 'CATEGORY_ID',
     permissionOverwrites: [{
         id: reactor,
         allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
     }]
});
```

Now I'd like to get that channels ID so that I can send a message in it after creation. I've been looking for answers but haven't found one that actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`channels.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) returns a promise with a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel) which has an `id` property. But you don't even need that ID, you can use the `.send` method on the newly created channel:

```js
const createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(`│${name}`, {
    type: 'text',
    parent: 'CATEGORY_ID',
     permissionOverwrites: [{
         id: reactor,
         allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
     }],
});

// createdChannel.id is the new channel's id
const { id } = createdChannel;

// but you can simply send a message with .send()
createdChannel.send('This is a message in the new channel');
```